# Extraer una imágen de la memoria externa y colocarla en un ImageView

Tags: android, android-fragment

Les pido ayuda para arreglar este código que se trata de extraer una imágen de los archivos de la memoria externa y colocarla en un ImageView.
Asi es como me los estan enseñando, pero me lo enseñan sobre la actividad principal `MainActivity` y funciona excelente, pero a mi me toca hacerlo en una clase que extiende de Fragment,por que tiene que trabajar con un cajón de navegación hago lo mismo que me enseñaron pero aparece un error en el `getContentResolver()`.
¿Qué es lo que me falta aquí?, les dejo el código de la clase fragment:

```
public class ImagenesFragment extends Fragment {

    private Button button,button2;

    ImageView imageView;
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private static final String[]PERMISOS={
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    };

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_imagenes,container,false);

        StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
        StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());

        imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.cargar_imagen);

        int leer = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int leer2 = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        if (leer== PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED && leer2 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),PERMISOS,REQUEST_CODE);
        }

        button = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_abrir);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(i,2);
            }
        });

        button2 = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_capturar);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                File imageFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"CamaraFolder");
                imageFolder.mkdir();

                File imagen = new File(imageFolder,"foto.jpg");

                Uri uriImagen = Uri.fromFile(imagen);

                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,uriImagen);

                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


        if (button != null) {
            if (requestCode == 2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                Uri imagenselccionada = data.getData();
                String[] path = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(imagenselccionada, path, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int columna = cursor.getColumnIndex(path[0]);
                String pathimagen = cursor.getString(columna);
                cursor.close();
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathimagen);
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                int height = bitmap.getHeight();
                int width = bitmap.getWidth();
                float scaleA = ((float) (width)) / width;
                float scaleB = ((float) (height)) / height;
                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                matrix.postScale(scaleA, scaleB);
                Bitmap nuevaimagen = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(nuevaimagen);
            }
        }if (button2!=null){
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Se ha guardado la imagen:\n"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "/CamaraFolder/foto.jpg",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"No se guardo correctamente la imagen en el dispositivo",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que lanzarle el contexto del **main** al **fragment** donde se desarrolla la actividad principal, o intenta hacer esto:

```
Cursor cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(imagenselccionada, path, null, null, null);
```

si no te funciona, crea una clase llamada variables y envia el context de la clase **MainActivity** y usa ese contexto desde el **fragment**.

Comment: Gracias amigo por la ayuda, me sirvio aplicarle el "getContext" antes del "getContentResolver" ya que el "getApplicationContext()" no lo reconcocia....si pudiera pedir nuevamente ayuda....como hago para detectar que boton activan en el mismo metodo onActivityResult que deje en la imagen de arriba, intente con: "if (button.isClickable()){" pero no me funciono...gracias de nuevo

Comment: Compañero, te recomendaria que quitaras el onActivityforResult() y crearas dos funciones diferentes para los eventos onClickListener() de los botones y envias los intent a cada funcion.

AndroidStudio utiliza los datos que envias mediante funciones como apuntadores, asi que estarias enviando el intent que tienes en el onClick.